# Find unparented test cases in TFS or MTM

Tags: tfs, microsoft-test-manager

I want to find a list of test cases that do not have any parent User Story for those. I used a migrator tool and uploaded a bunch of test cases from excel to TFS. I lost the test case IDs.

I need to link those test cases to their respective User Stories. So, is there any query that I can run to find the list of test cases that do not have a parent User Story to those?

I cannot query based on created date because these are imported over a period time and there were other team members who were writing hundred of test cases and linking it to the User Stories as well.

Any suggestion, please?

Comment: You would need to find an example of the test case in the TFS database then construct a SQL query to find them. The TFS UI hopefully would let you construct a similar query on test cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the type of quer: `work items and direct links` to list all the **Test cases** which not have a parent User Story to those. See below screenshot:

[image]